# this context in forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach

I was reading the [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), but I don't understand the `this` which is passed into the function. Could anyone explain more about the usage of the `this` argument here?

```
function Counter() {
  this.sum = 0;
  this.count = 0;
}

Counter.prototype.add = function(array) {
  array.forEach(function(entry) {
    this.sum += entry;
    ++this.count;
  }, this); //Why is this passed here?
};

var obj = new Counter();
obj.add([2, 5, 9]);
obj.count
// 3 
obj.sum
// 16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> `thisArg` Optional
>
> Value to use as `this` when executing callback.

And also:

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `forEach()`, **it will be passed to `callback` when invoked, for use as its `this` value.**  Otherwise, the value `undefined` will be passed for use as its `this` value. (Emphasis added)

What passing the `thisArg` to `forEach` does is bind the context. By default, `this` in `forEach` is the global `window` object, because `undefined` is used for `this`. Passing the context permits you to access things from that context.

In the prototype, `this` is the `Counter` constructor, and passing then allows you to set the context of which `this` is inside the `forEach`. So, instead of `this` being `window` inside the `forEach`, it is now `Counter`, and you can access variables such as `this.sum` otherwise not available due to the context.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @JacksonXie, Actually, if *any* answer is helpful, you should up-vote. For answers to questions you ask, if it is the answer which you personally used to solve your problem, then you should accept it. If it was both the solution you used and helpful (hard not to be helpful if it solved your problem), then you should both accept it *and* up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Since functions are self contained, your doing:

```
function x(){
  this.test = 5
}
```

it only exists within the scope of the function.

If you start nesting functions as you have, if you want the scope to remain the same, you need to inform the function just that.

It is along the same lines of using the `bind` function.

```
function test(){
  this.a = 4;
  var y = function(){
    this.a += 1;
  }.bind(this);
}
```

if you didnt bind, for example, this.a would would be undefined, so the line: `this.a += 1;` would be the same as saying: `this.a = undefined + 1`

but when you bind, it will say: `this.a = 4 + 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the scoping by using arrow function in es6.

> An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) expression has a shorter syntax compared to function
>   expressions and **does not bind its own this**, arguments, super, or
>   new.target.

```js
function Counter() {
  this.sum = 0;
  this.count = 0;
}

Counter.prototype.add = function(array) {
  array.forEach(entry=>{this.sum += entry;++this.count});
};

var obj = new Counter();
obj.add([2, 5, 9]);
console.log(obj);
```

This comes handy when the alternative methods available in es5 are using `bind()` to bind the `this` parameter, or using the `thisArg` that comes with `forEach` as already explained in the other answers.

Comment: Being a bit more verbose in your explanation would be good. Your single sentence would leave a naive reader wondering what you meant by "scoping" and "arrow function".  In other words, your answer does not stand alone. It requires the reader to have read other answers, and a bit about arrow functions. You don't even provide links with more explanation.

Comment: @Makyen Made some changes adding some more explanation. Thank you for noticing :)